# Differences in small and large companies

Tags: work-environment, new-job

I'm graduating from an engineering degree this year and would like to head towards a larger company, yet I have only had jobs or done experience in smaller companies.

what are some of the less obvious differences when going to a larger company?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've worked in both very small and large companies, I think it's very hard to generalise, I will just put the most important advantage and disadvantage of each:

**Disadvantages of small companies:**
Most important consideration I think you should make is that when changing jobs in the future, small companies don't look nearly as good on CV. It's highly likely nobody has ever heard of your small company you work for. Even if you are doing the exact same job in a small company it's much more impressive being a Javascript developer at Google than a Javascript Developer for John Doe consulting.

**Disadvantages of large companies:** Processes and bureaucracy are no fun at all, but come with the territory of large companies. In general large companies are extremely risk-averse, resulting in creating a process for just about anything as to make sure nothing bad happens. This in-turn creates bureaucracy and it can be very hard to figure out how to get permission and who can help you, when there isn't a well defined process in-front of you, which can mean doing the same job in a large company can be much more painful and time consuming than the same task in a smaller company.

**Advantage of small companies:** Potential, if I think about what is the best advantage it is that there is a massive potential, however unlikely, that the company grows rapidly and you come to hold a very strong position in the company. I stress this is very unlikely, but often with startups you might be the only developer yet your job title is CTO or head of engineering, (pretty much head of nothing but yourself), but if you acquire a senior position early on you will have a great one later. This isn't so much the case in a large company. It is sort of a scale out scenario most of the time, you don't really get promoted, but instead less desk space as more people are added.

**Advantage of large companies:** Stability and Reliability. Generally large companies are a very stable job to be in. Opposite to a small company, everyone will know the company you worked for, making it easier to get a job in the future. If you play your cards right, you can climb the hill and get promotions, unlike with a small company you will actually have to build the hill first, and hope your business lets you climb afterwards.

There is plenty of other things could go on forever but these I feel are some of the most important.a I do think though you should be more focused on finding what job you will enjoy the most no matter where that is.

Answer (score 0):

Off the top of my head...

- Larger companies with have more strict HR practices that can limit your pay and benefits, whereas with a smaller company those actions can be based on a single decision maker.  Flip side is larger companies will offer more workplace protections.
- Larger companies will generally be more stable compared to smaller companies where you may come into work one day to find the doors locked and everybody laid off, or have payroll terms of 'We'll pay you when we feel we have the money'.
- Smaller companies can often have multiple relatives working there which can dominate decisions and promotions.
- Larger companies may take greater chances on hiring students right out of college as there is greater opportunities.

This question is really too general to offer details, but this is a shot.